# python3 pdb display list

Tags: python-3.x, pdb

The `display` command of pdb seems to only show an expression when the whole variable is assigned.

```
pass
foo = [1, 2, 3]
foo[0] = 8
foo.append(7)
pass
```

The output I get when running the above code with `python3 -m pdb bar.py` and then entering `display foo` is:

```
> bar.py(2)<module>()
-> foo = [1, 2, 3]
(Pdb) display foo
display foo: ** raised NameError: name 'foo' is not defined **
(Pdb) n
> bar.py(3)<module>()
-> foo[0] = 8
display foo: [1, 2, 3]  [old: ** raised NameError: name 'foo' is not defined **]
(Pdb) 
> bar.py(4)<module>()
-> foo.append(7)
(Pdb) 
> bar.py(5)<module>()
-> pass
(Pdb) foo
[8, 2, 3, 7]
(Pdb)
```

The NameError and the first output of display are expected.
However it seems that display does not catch that `foo` changed when its first item was changed or when we appended 7.

Is there a way to tell pdb to list those changes?
It seems that `display str(foo)` does the job but I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way to track those changes is to you `'p'` command instead. See this example

```
> /home/maksim/Projects/Python/basic/test.py(2)<module>()
-> foo = [1, 2, 3]
(Pdb) s;;l;;p foo
> /home/maksim/Projects/Python/basic/test.py(3)<module>()
-> foo[0] = 8
  1     pass
  2     foo = [1, 2, 3]
  3  -> foo[0] = 8
  4     foo.append(7)
  5     pass
  6     
  7     
  8     
[EOF]
[1, 2, 3]
(Pdb) s;;l;;p foo
> /home/maksim/Projects/Python/basic/test.py(4)<module>()
-> foo.append(7)
  1     pass
  2     foo = [1, 2, 3]
  3     foo[0] = 8
  4  -> foo.append(7)
  5     pass
  6     
  7     
  8     
[EOF]
[8, 2, 3]
(Pdb) s;;l;;p foo
> /home/maksim/Projects/Python/basic/test.py(5)<module>()
-> pass
  1     pass
  2     foo = [1, 2, 3]
  3     foo[0] = 8
  4     foo.append(7)
  5  -> pass
  6     
  7     
  8     
[EOF]
[8, 2, 3, 7]
(Pdb) s;;l;;p foo
--Return--
> /home/maksim/Projects/Python/basic/test.py(5)<module>()->None
-> pass
  1     pass
  2     foo = [1, 2, 3]
  3     foo[0] = 8
  4     foo.append(7)
  5  -> pass
  6     
  7     
  8     
[EOF]
[8, 2, 3, 7]
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it does not entirely answer my question. Printing would print the content of foo even if it has not changed which I would have liked to avoid.

Comment: Oh, I see... yeah, you are right it doesn't. I'll post a comment if something better is going to appear. And sorry for answering instead of commenting - my reputation is only 18 points for now so I simply can't comment any user's questions but only my own. Thank's for your reply.